# select fields with sed

Tags: bash, sed

Using only grep and sed, is there a way I can tranform the output of `ls -l *` into  this :

-rw-r--r-- agenda.txt

-rw-r--r-- annuaire.txt

Thanks!

Comment: yes :) and sed is so powerful!

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: If you are not doing homework(Using only grep and sed). Please try `stat -c '%A %n' *`(handle white space nicely)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like this?

```
ls -l | sed 's/ [0-9].*:.[0-9] / /' | less
```

Transforms

```
-rw-r--r--  1 tomislav tomislav     609 2009-11-26 10:32 Test.class
-rw-r--r--  1 tomislav tomislav      46 2009-12-14 12:16 test.groovy
```

into

```
-rw-r--r-- Test.class
-rw-r--r-- test.groovy
```

Comment: This will fail for files where `ls` prints the year instead of hh:mm.

Comment: I've provided some test input, the command and the output I get: I am sure it works that way because that is a copy/paste of what I got.
Hlovdal, the year doesn't show up for any of my files instead of hh:mm.
Dennis, always glad to see someone reduce/improve: you are right, the 'g' is not needed.

Comment: From the core-utils info manual: "By default, file timestamps are listed in abbreviated form.  Most
locales use a timestamp like `2002-03-30 23:45'.  However, the default
POSIX locale uses a date like `Mar 30  2002' for non-recent timestamps,
and a date-without-year and time like `Mar 30 23:45' for recent
timestamps. A timestamp is considered to be "recent" if it is less than six
months old"

Comment: I have files modified in 2008 and they still show yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm <filename>. Judging by Samantha's comment, it's just ubuntu's default behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

seeing that you have already got your "answer", here's one of the simpler solution

```
 ls -l | tr -s " "| cut -d" " -f1,8-
```

@OP, sed is "powerful", but sometimes, simplicity is more `powerful`.

Side note: Don't parse file names like that.

Comment: I agree with you ghostdog, but I just needed to learn a couple tricks with sed... Thanks :)

Comment: Of all the given answers, I consider this to be the best one from a robustness point of view. All of the sed answers will fail in case of filenames with an unfortunate combination of colon, space and/or numbers in them. This solution will not fail that way.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ls -l | sed 's/[ ]+//g' | sed 's/ [0-9].*:.[0-9]/ /g'
```

Comment: Hey, tested your command, and noticed that the first part | sed 's/[ ]+//g' doesn't really do much :) it works just fine whitout it... did you add it for a particular purpose?

Comment: I assume the first sed command is intended to be the same as `tr -s " "` as in ghostdog74's answer. The correct syntax for that is `sed 's/[ ]\+/ /g'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -altrh| sed -E 's/ +.+ / / g'
```

Or you can go with ssed which supports Perl Regular Expressions.

I solved your problem using the `ssed` program you can install it in any Posix system, `ssed` stands for super sed.
so i did a `ls -latrh` in my home directory.

```
telsa:~ mahmoh$ ls -altrh

total 136
drwxr-xr-x   5 root    admin   170B Jun 24 00:27 ../
drwx------+  4 mahmoh  staff   136B Jun 24 00:27 Pictures/
drwx------+  3 mahmoh  staff   102B Jun 24 00:27 Music/
drwx------+  3 mahmoh  staff   102B Jun 24 00:27 Movies/
drwx------+  3 mahmoh  staff   102B Jun 24 00:27 Desktop/
-rw-------   1 mahmoh  staff     3B Jun 24 00:27 .CFUserTextEncoding
drwxr-xr-x+  5 mahmoh  staff   170B Jun 24 00:27 Public/
drwx------+  5 mahmoh  staff   170B Jun 24 02:19 Documents/
-rw-r--r--@  1 mahmoh  staff    15K Jun 24 02:19 .DS_Store
drwx------@ 36 mahmoh  staff   1.2K Jun 24 14:48 Library/
-rw-r--r--   1 mahmoh  staff   279B Jun 24 15:27 .profile~
-rw-r--r--@  1 mahmoh  staff    14K Jun 24 15:29 .vimrc
-rw-r--r--   1 mahmoh  staff   279B Jun 24 15:30 .profile
drwx------   2 mahmoh  staff    68B Jun 24 15:46 .Trash/
drwxr-xr-x   3 mahmoh  staff   102B Jun 24 20:26 .mplayer/
-rw-------   1 mahmoh  staff   3.5K Jun 24 22:11 .bash_history
-rw-------   1 mahmoh  staff    42B Jun 24 23:25 .lesshst
-rw-r--r--   1 mahmoh  staff   3.6K Jun 24 23:39 temp
-rw-r--r--   1 mahmoh  staff   3.3K Jun 24 23:43 rtorrent.rc~
drwxr-xr-x   5 mahmoh  staff   170B Jun 24 23:52 torrents/
-rw-r--r--   1 mahmoh  staff   3.3K Jun 24 23:56 .rtorrent.rc~
-rw-------   1 mahmoh  staff   3.7K Jun 24 23:56 .viminfo
-rw-r--r--   1 mahmoh  staff   3.3K Jun 24 23:56 .rtorrent.rc
drwxr-xr-x+ 25 mahmoh  staff   850B Jun 24 23:56 ./
drwx------+ 10 mahmoh  staff   340B Jun 24 23:58 Downloads/
```

Now watch.

```
telsa:~ mahmoh$ ls -altrh| ssed -R -e 's/ +.+ /    / g'
total 136
drwxr-xr-x    ../
drwx------+    Pictures/
drwx------+    Music/
drwx------+    Movies/
drwx------+    Desktop/
-rw-------    .CFUserTextEncoding
drwxr-xr-x+    Public/
drwx------+    Documents/
-rw-r--r--@    .DS_Store
drwx------@    Library/
-rw-r--r--    .profile~
-rw-r--r--@    .vimrc
-rw-r--r--    .profile
drwx------    .Trash/
drwxr-xr-x    .mplayer/
-rw-------    .bash_history
-rw-------    .lesshst
-rw-r--r--    temp
-rw-r--r--    rtorrent.rc~
drwxr-xr-x    torrents/
-rw-r--r--    .rtorrent.rc~
-rw-------    .viminfo
-rw-r--r--    .rtorrent.rc
drwxr-xr-x+    ./
drwx------+    Downloads/
```

Comment: never heard of super sed before. big ups.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working command. The slightly tricky thing is that `ls -l` will print the year for files that are older than some time (6 months) and `hh:mm` for newer files.

```
ls -l  | sed 's/ .*[0-9]* .*[A-Z][a-z][a-z] [ 0-9][0-9] \{1,2\}[0-9][0-9]:*[0-9][0-9] / /'
```

For the following example

> drwxr-xr-x  39 root     root        1024 Feb 19 08:58 /

the starting `.*` will match `39 root     root        1024` and then the rest of the regular expression matches month name (so you might restrict a-z to fewer characters) followed by year or hh:mm.

Comment: What does not work? I have tested and verified the command on a solaris 10 machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -l | sed 's/^\([^\t ]\+\)\(.*:.[^ \t]\+\)\(.\+\)/\1 \3/'
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use awk instead of sed? awk is built for stuff like this.

see [this manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fields.html) for more about fields in awk.